# Удаление на промежутке в multiset

Tags: c++, алгоритм, delete, multiset

Как в `multiset` удалять элементы на промежутке `[first, last]` (рамки промежутка вводятся с консоли)?
first и last - условные позиции элементов, если бы они имели индексы

Comment: Промежутки в multiset задаются парой итераторов. Значения итераторов никак не могут "вводиться с консоли". Уточните формулировку вопроса.

Comment: first и last - условные позиции элементов, если бы они имели индексы. Пробовал как в векторе, но здесь другая реализация

Comment: Вопрос обладает признаками XY-problem. Контейнер `multiset` не поддерживает произвольного (индексного) доступа и тот факт, что вам вдруг понадобилось этот доступ эмулировать "костыльным" образом скорее всего говорит о том, что вы что-то делаете неправильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы имеете в виду что-то вроде этого

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    std::multiset<int> set = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };

    for ( const auto &i : set ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int lower = 3, upper = 7;

    set.erase( set.lower_bound( lower ), set.upper_bound( upper ) );

    for ( const auto &i : set ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 2 4 6 8 
0 2 8
```

Если вы имеете в виду что-то вроде индексов, то код может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::multiset<int> set = { 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8 };

    for ( const auto &i : set ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::multiset<int>::size_type lower = 3, upper = 5;

    set.erase( std::next( std::begin( set ), lower ), 
               std::next( std::begin( set ), upper + 1 ) );

    for ( const auto &i : set ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 2 2 4 4 4 6 6 8 
0 2 2 6 6 8
```

То есть удаляются элементы с "индексами" 3, 4, 5. Индексация ведется от 0.

Вы можете также вставить проверку индексов, что они не выходят за допустимый диапазон. Например, проверку для верхнего индекса может выглядеть так, как показано в демонстрационной программе ниже

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::multiset<int> set = { 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8 };

    for ( const auto &i : set ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::multiset<int>::size_type lower = 3, upper = 10;

    upper = upper < set.size() ? upper + 1 : set.size();

    set.erase( std::next( std::begin( set ), lower ), 
               std::next( std::begin( set ), upper ) );

    for ( const auto &i : set ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
0 2 2 4 4 4 6 6 8 
0 2 2
```